# if-then block using grep and logical OR (||) question in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have the following if-then block in a Bash function declaration, using `grep` and a logical OR (||):

`if grep -q <somepattern> <file> || grep -q <somepattern> <file2>; then`

The above works well, yay!!

But I went to "clean this up" a bit and thought this should be the same, but fails:

`if [ grep -q <somepattern> <file> ] || [ grep -q <somepattern> <file2> ]; then`

or

`if [ grep -q <somepattern> <file> || grep -q <somepattern> <file2> ]; then`

I get this error:

```
-bash: [: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
```

I thought that not using `[[ $(<foo>) ]]` syntax would be safe and reduce clutter, but it is not clear to me why this does not work. Have googled around a bit and it still unclear to me why this fails.

as an interesting side note, this is ok:

`if [ $(grep -q <somepattern> <file>) ] || [ $(grep -q <somepattern> <file2>) ]; then`

my thinking was the `$(..)` wrapping the grep statements is overkill as the `[..]` would be looking for the return from grep.

I `set -x` to get some clues and I see this:

```
+ '[' grep -q <somepattern> <file> ']'
-bash: [: too many arguments
+ '[' grep -q <somepattern> <file2> ']'
-bash: [: too many arguments
```

My understanding of `test` leads me to believe this should work, obviously not. Though maybe this has to do with the observation that `test` will not execute the grep command inside `[..]` or `[[..]]` blocks, hence success with `grep` enclosed in `$(..)` syntax

Anyone want to shed a bit more light onto this for me?

Comment: `[` is not bash syntax at all, it's an alias for the command also named `test`. You should just run `if grep -q`, not `if [ grep -q`.

Comment: ...and just as `foo || bar` runs two simple commands, `foo` and `bar` with a short-circuiting logical OR between them, `[ grep -q <somepattern> <file> || grep -q <somepattern> <file2> ]` runs two separate commands, `[ grep -q <somepattern> <file>` and `grep -q <somepattern> <file2> ]`. Because these are separate commands, the `[` before the first one is not matched with the `]` after the second.

Comment: Ok thanks! That helps. I stated below, I has a poor understanding of ```test``` ```[``` block. This has helped. Cheers!

Comment: It's not really a "block" at all; it's just a regular command, treated the same as anything else -- `ls` or `echo` or whatnot -- insofar as parsing is concerned, with the caveat that when it's called under the name `[`, it expects to see a `]` as its final argument. (By contrast, when called under the name `test`, it has no such expectation).

Comment: yeah. That has made the difference to me: …it's not really a "block"

Years of writing scripts and I just had these baked in conventions I used to make them work, never really bother to understand why, well until now . Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` simply runs a command, checks if its return code is `0` (true) or anything else (false) before picking a branch to execute.

`[` (and `test`) is simply one possible command for it to run, a very popular and useful command. But it doesn't do what you want in this case. You want something more feature complex, a grep of a file. A grep of two files, potentially, actually.

All you need to do is ensure that the command (singular...ish) you run after `if` returns 0 in case it results in the behaviour you want to check for, and non-0 otherwise.  In your case, `grep ... || grep ...` returns 0 when you want to run the extra commands, and non-0 otherwise.  There is no `test` functionality that matches this, so you have, more or less, the right idea to start with.

Comment: Ok thanks, this helps my understanding!!

I think I need better understanding of ```test```.  :).

I experimented replacing the ```[..]``` block with ```test``` statements. My confusion seems to be my previous belief that what was inside of a ```test``` or ```[``` block is interpreted like a shell command itself; similar to enclosing the ```grep``` in ```$(..)``` as implied functionality of ```test```, that was my problem, it would need to be more explicit. Thanks again,